# React Native Pod error No such file or directory .pm2

Tags: javascript, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

I am trying to set up the `pod` to get the camera permissions. Apparently, the `pod` cannot find the `.pm2` file or directory when running `pod install` or `pod setup`.

```
A:\App>pod setup
internal/fs/utils.js:332
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'A:\Users\pydar\.pm2'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:1013:3)
    at Object.CLI.pm2Init (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pod\node_modules\pm2\lib\CLI.js:39:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pod\lib\api.js:41:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at loadAPI (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pod\lib\cli.js:244:11) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'A:\\Users\\user\\.pm2'
}
```

Comment: try `npm i -g pm2`

Comment: same issue persisting